# Powershell Copy-Item - Exclude only if the file exists in destination

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, copy-item

Following is the exact scenario in my powershell script.

```
$Source = "C:\MyTestWebsite\"
$Destination = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite"
$ExcludeItems = @(".config", ".csproj")

Copy-Item "$Source\*" -Destination "$Destination" -Exclude $ExcludeItems -Recurse -Force
```

I want this code to copy .config and .csproj files if they are not existing in destination folder. The current script simply excludes them irrespective to whether they exist or not.
The objective is,I do not want the script to overwrite .config and .csproj files, but it should copy them if they are not existing at destination.

Any idea of what corrections are required in the scripts?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some sort of If statement using Test-Path would seem to be in order.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Robocopy, not a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be pretty close to what you want to do

```
$Source = "C:\MyTestWebsite\"
$Destination = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite"

$ExcludeItems = @()
if (Test-Path "$Destination\*.config")
{
    $ExcludeItems += "*.config"
}
if (Test-Path "$Destination\*.csproj")
{
    $ExcludeItems += "*.csproj"
}

Copy-Item "$Source\*" -Destination "$Destination" -Exclude $ExcludeItems -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Source = "C:\MyTestWebsite"
$Destination = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite"

$sourceFileList = Get-ChildItem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite" -Recurse

foreach ($item in $sourceFileList)
{
    $destinationPath = $item.Path.Replace($Source,$Destination)
    #For every *.csproj and *.config files, check whether the file exists in destination
    if ($item.extension -eq ".csproj" -or $item.extension -eq ".config")
    {
        if ((Test-Path $destinationPath) -ne $true)
        {
            Copy-Item $item -Destination $destinationPath -Force
        }
    }
    #If not *.csproj or *.config file then copy it directly
    else
    {
        Copy-Item $item -Destination $destinationPath -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SKaDT's solution worked for me.

```
Copy-Item -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\source\*.iso).FullName -Destination E:\destination -Exclude (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\destination\*.iso).Name -Verbose
```

`(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\source\*.iso).FullName` will collect all source files with full drive, path and filenames. With `-Exclude` parameter, `(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\destination\*.iso).Name` collects all *.iso files in the destination folder and excludes all of them.
Result: copy all *.iso files from source to destination but excludes all *.iso files that exist in the destination folder.

Answer (score -1):

## you can use that oneline command to copy only files that did't exist at destination location, for Task Scheduler for example

```
Copy-Item -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\source\*.iso).FullName -Destination E:\destination -Exclude (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\destination\*.iso).Name -Verbose
```

## cmdlet get all files on folder by mask (*.iso), after that seek the destination folder and exclude all filenames that exist at destination folder

Comment: Welcome! Please include an explanation with your answer. Code only answers get sent to the "Low Quality Posts" review queue for potential deletion. You can always edit and improve on your answer.